# Referring instance method of Arbitrary Object in Java using Double Colon Operator

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
class Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "Point(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
    }
    
    boolean filter() {
        return this.x == this.y;
    }
    
}
 
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Point> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Point(0, 0));
        list.add(new Point(1, 2));
        list.add(new Point(-1, -1));
        Supplier<Boolean> s = Point::filter; // Compilation Error (line n1)
        list.stream().filter(Point::filter).forEach(System.out::println); //No Error (line n2)
    }
}
```

On line n2, if I access an instance method using Classname, then implicitly an arbitrary object is created an accessed, but on line n1, I get Compilation error.
In which scenarios, arbitrary implicit objects are created?

I dont get error if I use an object

```
new Point(0,0)::filter
```

Comment: I assume you have read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In which scenarios, arbitrary implicit objects are created?

In *neither* scenario, do new objects get created.

`Supplier<Boolean> s = Point::filter;` doesn't compile because a `Supplier<Boolean>` represents a function that can give you a `Boolean` *without you giving it any input*, i.e. I should be able to do:

```
Boolean b = s.get(); // note that I am not giving "get" any input
// but s refers to the filter method in Point, which is an instance method
// I don't have any Point object in my code, yet somehow I still got a Boolean,
//  so clearly this doesn't make sense
```

As you can see, `Point::filter` is not such a function. To call it, I would need to give it a `Point` object first, and then it would give me a `boolean`. `Predicate<Point>` is a functional interface that can represent this kind of function, so I can do:

```
Predicate<Point> pred = Point::filter;
boolean b = pred.test(new Point(0, 0)); // here I am giving red the instance of Point on which filter should be called
```

Note how you don't specify which object `filter` should be called on in the method reference (`Point::filter`), but rather it is specified by the caller (`pred.test(...)`). This is why `Point::filter` is called a "reference to an instance method of an *arbitrary* object".

Lastly, the reason why `Stream.filter` can accept your `Point::filter` method is because [it actually takes a `Predicate<Point>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-), rather than a `Supplier<Boolean>` as parameter!

When you call `forEach`, `Point::filter` is called *on each stream element*. Exactly how it does this is down to the implementation details of the stream pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, It confused me when I read an explanation which stated that a new object is created implicitly.

Comment: @JonB Maybe the explanation was saying that a _parameter_ accepting an instance is created implicitly? e.g. `Point:foo` actually needs one parameter of type `Point`, whereas `foo` doesn't declare any parameters.

Comment: Yes that was the explanation, I misunderstood it